# How do I unlock the level 2 ability of the Sword of the Griffin?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

I'm playing through the second mission of the tutorial campaign in Heroes 6 and the only remaining quest (short of finishing the mission) is to get attuned to the Sword of the Griffin.

I'm online and connected to the CONFLUX servers, so that's not an issue. I also thought that I had to reach dynasty level 2 and the quest would complete, but that doesn't seem to be the case either.

What do I have to do, exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heroes of Might and Magic VI (Or whatever anagram thereof they're calling it) tracks Weapon experience separately from Dynasty Experience.

*In short:*

- **Dynasty** Levels go up to 50, and unlock Tiers at the altar of wishes.
- **Weapon** Levels go up to 5, and unlock new passive bonuses or active combat abilities.

In both cases, however, leveling them up is the same - winning battles. In the case of the weapons, the dynasty weapon in question must be wielded by a hero in the battle.

So... what do you have to do? Win more battles! You've not reached Weapon level 2, you've reached *Dynasty* level 2.

**Final Note:** Don't be discouraged by the seemingly insane numbers you need to reach weapon levels 3, 4, and 5. Is it a lot? Yes. But in the last map of each campaign, when you're routinely slaying 100's of angels (or angel-analogue) per fight, it adds up quick.

Comment: Hrm. With the tutorial campaign apparently only having two missions, is there any way for me to reach weapon level 2 now that I've pretty much cleared the map and maxed out the hero's level?

Comment: @AnnaLear You could play it again. The sword's XP won't reset.

Comment: Reaching your hero's lvl cap also doesn't stop your dynasty or weapon from gaining xp.

Answer (score 1):

To make it easier you can just use the Soul Forge on the Conflux web. It takes 10 min. to upgrade any weapon to level 2. After you load your saved game next time the mission will be completed.